# How do I style a select element in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Right now I have a dropdown menu which looks like this:

[image: What i have now]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: Image how must be]

How can I style the HTML `select` element so that it becomes transparent like in the picture?

The `GermanyLanguage` component loads the SVG file for the flag.  The `SwitcherContent` is a `div` styled by the styled-components package.

```
  return (
    <>
      <SwitcherContent>
        <GermanyLanguage />
        <select
          name="select"
          style={{ width: 120, marginLeft: 8 }}
          defaultValue={intl.locale}
          onChange={(e) => changeLocale(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="de">deutsch</option>
          <option value="en">english</option>
        </select>
      </SwitcherContent>
    </>
  );

export const SwitcherContent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

background: 'bottom' dint help me , now switcher looks like [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tpVh.png)

Comment: Every browser defines its own base stylesheet for built-in elements like `select`.  You need to override all of the default styled properties, for example set `background: transparent;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every browser defines its own base stylesheet for built-in elements like select. You need to override all of the default styled properties with the styles that you want.

You can change the styles by adding properties to the `style` prop like you have done with `style={{ width: 120, marginLeft: 8 }}`, by using styled-components like you have done with `SwitcherContent = styled.div`, or by declaring classes in a CSS file and setting the `className` prop on your components.

You will need to override `background`, `color`, `border`, and possibly more.  The `background` property could be `transparent`, `unset`, or `black`.

This should get you started in the right direction:

```
return (
  <>
    <SwitcherContent>
      <GermanyLanguage />
      <select
        style={{
          width: 120,
          marginLeft: 8,
          background: "black",
          color: "white",
          border: "none"
        }}
        name="select"
        defaultValue={intl.locale}
        onChange={(e) => changeLocale(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="de">deutsch</option>
        <option value="en">english</option>
      </select>
    </SwitcherContent>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.

```
<GermanyLanguage/> -> SVG file
  return (
    <>
      <SwitcherContent>
        <GermanyLanguage />
        <select
          name="select"
          style={{ width: 120, marginLeft: 8, background:"bottom" }}
          defaultValue={intl.locale}
          onChange={(e) => changeLocale(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="de">deutsch</option>
          <option value="en">english</option>
        </select>
      </SwitcherContent>
    </>
  );

export const SwitcherContent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Comment: Didn't help I loaded the image as it looks after background: 'bottom'